# ResultReceiver vs Messenger

Tags: android, android-service, android-messaging

I'm implementing a REST client according to the first method of this presentation - http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

currently I'm using a `ResultReceiver` for the "binder callback" between the service and the service helper,

is there any reason I should prefer a `Messenger` over `ResultReceiver` or the opposite for this?